# Writing to txt in python

Tags: python, text

I'm writing lines of numbers to a text file from another text file. The numbers that print while this is running look good, but when I open the output file nothing has been written to it. Can't figure out why.

```
min1=open(output1,"w")



oh_reader = open(filename, 'r')

countmin = 0

   while countmin <=300000:
        for line in oh_reader:

       #min1 
        if countmin <=60000:
            hrvalue= int(line)
            ibihr = line
            print(line)
            print(countmin)
            min1.write(ibihr)
            min1.write("\n")
            countmin = countmin + hrvalue


min1.close()
```

Comment: Indentation is broken. If-statement needs to be right-shifted one step---

Comment: print(line) doesn't print all file? I think you want for line in oh_reader.readline(); and the comments about bad indentation are valid to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Python's `with` statement to open files. It handles closing for you and is generally safer:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as oh_reader:
```

If this is the way your program is indented

```
min1=open(output1,"w")



oh_reader = open(filename, 'r')

countmin = 0

   while countmin <=300000:
        for line in oh_reader:
            # this is the same as having pass here
       #min1 
        if countmin <=60000:
            hrvalue= int(line)
            ibihr = line
            print(line)
            print(countmin)
            min1.write(ibihr)
            min1.write("\n")
            countmin = countmin + hrvalue
min1.close()
```

The `for` loop is empty so nothing will be executed. To fix this:

```
min1=open(output1,"w")

oh_reader = open(filename, 'r')

countmin = 0

   while countmin <=300000:
        for line in oh_reader:
            #min1 
            if countmin <=60000:
                hrvalue= int(line)
                ibihr = line
                print(line)
                print(countmin)
                min1.write(ibihr)
                min1.write("\n")
                countmin = countmin + hrvalue
min1.close()
```

Or alternatively:

```
min1=open(output1,"w")

oh_reader = open(filename, 'r')

countmin = 0

for line in oh_reader:
    #min1 
    if countmin <=60000:
        hrvalue= int(line)
        ibihr = line
        print(line)
        print(countmin)
        min1.write(ibihr)
        min1.write("\n")
        countmin += hrvalue  # += operator is equal to a = a + b
min1.close()
```

Comment: Since `oh_reader` will be consumed after the first pass, there is no need for the outer `while-loop` either.

Comment: @unutbu I assumed as much but I'm not sure about the rest of the OP's program. Didn't want to change it too much. I'll post an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain of the logic, but I think this is what you want:

```
IN_FNAME  = 'abc.txt'
OUT_FNAME = 'def.txt'

with open(IN_FNAME) as inf, open(OUT_FNAME, 'w') as outf:
    total = 0
    for line in inf:
        val = int(line)
        total += val

        if total <= 60000:
            print('{} -> {}'.format(val, total))
            outf.write('{}\n'.format(val))
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Clearly the OP is not an expert in python, so giving this with no explanation will not help them learn anything.